# Bootstrap/Laravel won't load javascripts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I try to load my javascripts like this:

```
                        <!-- Le javascript -->
<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

 {{ HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-transition.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-alert.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-modal.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-dropdown.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-tab.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-tooltip.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-popover.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-button.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-collapse.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-carousel.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-typeahead.js') }}
```

But still, it doesn't load. I've checked the console in Chrome Developer Tools, and it returns for the most of them the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-transition.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-alert.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-modal.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bootstrap-tab.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bootstrap-popover.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-button.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-collapse.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-carousel.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8000/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js:4
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "chrome-extension://gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg/js/inject.js".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using a CDN like:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

ie just have this to replace all you have:

```
{{ HTML::script('http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's like your first char in those JS is a <. I see that like a first char of a HTML tag.
Are you sure of your JS path ?